# A proof for the converse of Lagrange's Theorem (for finite abelian groups).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I must follow two instructions to prove the converse of Lagrange's Theorem for finite abelian groups.

First I must prove $(\star)$

> Let $q_1,\dots,q_n\in\mathbb{N}$  and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $k\mid (q_1\cdot\dots\cdot q_n)$,
>
> Prove there exists $k_1,\dots,k_n$ such that $k=k_1\cdot\cdots k_n$
> and $k_i\mid q_i$

I tried and I think my proof is correct
[Prove there exists $k_1,\dots,k_n$ such that $k=k_1\cdot\cdots k_n$ and $k_i\mid p_i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4315618/prove-there-exists-k-1-dots-k-n-such-that-k-k-1-cdot-cdots-k-n-and-k-i-mid)

Now I must proof ( $\star \star)$

> Let $G$ a finite abelian Group, $|G|=n$ and $k|n$, prove there exists
> $K\leq G$ and $|K|=k$

So I read many proofs and the idea of all of them is :

1. $|G|=n=p_1^{l_1}\dots p_j^{l_j}$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic
2. $k|n$ then $k=p_1^{m_1}\dots p_j^{mj}$
3. By the first Sylow theorem there exists $K_i\leq G$ and $|K_i|=p_i^{m_i}$
4. Finally $K=K_1\dots K_j\leq G$ and $|K|=p_1^{m_1}\dots p_j^{mj}=k$

My question is **why is necessary to prove $(\star)$?**

Finally is just $K$ the only subgroup of order $k?$ I think it is not because the Klein-4 Group has 3 subgroups of order 2.

Comment: How does 3 follow from the first Sylow theorem?

Comment: It seems to me that there is an easier way to prove the converse of Lagrange's Theorem for finite abelian groups.
One can use induction on the order of $G$:
1. If $p$ is prime and $p\mid n$, then group $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$.
2. Let $k\mid n$, $k>1$ and $p$ be a prime divisor of $k$. Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $p$. By induction, the factor group $G/A$ has a subgroup $H/A$ of order $k/p$. We have $|H|=k$.